# How to fix 'The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/portlet cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application'

Tags: java, liferay-7

When I add `<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/portlet' prefix='portlet' %>` to JSP file, I get an exception

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.1</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Exception:

```
2019-04-10 11:28:17.573 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-6][PortletRequestDispatcherImpl:331] Unable to dispatch request: /jsp/departments.jsp(9,62) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/portlet cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
2019-04-10 11:28:17.574 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-6][PortletServlet:112] javax.portlet.PortletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/departments.jsp(9,62) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/portlet cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
javax.portlet.PortletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/departments.jsp(9,62) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/portlet cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
     at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:333)
     at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:145)
```

Answer (score 0):

change <%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/portlet' prefix='portlet' %> to <%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0' prefix='portlet' %>